# How can I change an apk's internal name?

Tags: android, apk

I have an apk file that I did not create, which has the internal name `com.android.gallery3d`. However, It is not the stock app, but a modified version (2160p Player) with subtitle support, among other things. How can I change the internal name so that it is not `com.android.gallery3d`? It needs to be different because I can't install it because it conflicts with the existing system app. Do I need to edit the manifest and resign the apk? How do I do this? I have access to Windows and Ubuntu-based Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack, change, repack and resign. Use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) or a similar tool.

Comment: You can only do this if you created the apk (poster mentioned he didn't), or if you have the signing key of the apk. If you can do adb with your device, try "adb install -r <apk name>"

Comment: Of course not. You just sign it with your own key. If the app is not already installed and you are not trying it update it, the signing key doesn't matter.